# Docusign connect, need to buy SSL certificate?

Tags: tomcat7, docusignapi

For all docusign developers outthere. I'm using Docusign Connect to check the status of the envelop. I develop a listener that runs on tomcat. The reason why I used this because it's easier to code on my perspective and I want a push type data notification.
It works fine with HTTP, but I spend 2 days now and I still can't get it work for HTTPS.

My question is since the self signed certificate is not working. **Do I need to purchase an SSL certificate for my web server?**

**or Docusign has a work around on this?**

Answer (score 1):

On demo sandboxes you can get away with testing without using HTTPS.
On production you will need a server that will actually support error free SSL connections. This means that you will need to wire up your tomcat to use some certificate that validates your website address.  Whether it's a new one or just a wild card that you already have - that depends on the situation.

HTH
-mb